# Angular: ng build --prod produces Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormGroup'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

For some reason, I have a bunch of things break when I build my angular project in production that worked fine in dev.  They are all pretty much the same so I'll illustrate with one example.

I have a form where at the end of each section there is a button that checks the validity of a particular FormGroup as follows:

```
<button md-button color="primary" (click)="checkValidity(changeForm.get('changeOverviewFG'))">Check</button>
```

And the function looks like this in my component class.

```
  checkValidity(g: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
      g.get(key).markAsDirty();
    });
    Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
      g.get(key).markAsTouched();
    });
    Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
      g.get(key).updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }
```

When I build it in dev everything works fine and it performs as intended.  But when I try to build it with --prod, I get the following error

**Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormGroup'.**

So suddenly it's trying to read a FormGroup as an Abstract control in production?  Either way in my template I have quite a number of instances that are getting this type of error, so if possible the fix would be preferable in the component class.

Is there any way I can explicitly cast an AbstractControl as a FormGroup (I haven't found anything anywhere suggesting this is possible) or is there another easy way to approach this problem?

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10192
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6099

Those were two references that came the closest to being relevant to my problem but the solutions presented in there don't apply to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got things working in prod by passing in objects instead of FormGroups or FormControls, and then casting them afterwards.  In the case of my question, I changed it to the following.

```
checkValidity(h: Object) {
  const g = <FormGroup>h;
  Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
    g.get(key).markAsDirty();
  });
  Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
    g.get(key).markAsTouched();
  });
  Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
    g.get(key).updateValueAndValidity();
  });
}
```

Big thanks to the anonymous downvote with no feedback though!  I'm sure that certainly fits in the culture of this site.